# Creating a multiple URL vCard using vObject

Tags: vcf-vcard, vobject

**How can I get multiple URL in one VCard.**

I am using VObject library (https://pypi.org/project/vobject/)

I want to create a VCard with details like:

- Fname
- Lname
- Company name
- Phone number
- address
- **website url**
- **facebook url**
- **insta gram url**
- **Tik tok url**
- **twitter url**

I tried the following code

```
    vCard.add('URL')
    vCard.url.value = 'https://www.example.com'
    vCard.url.type_param = "Website:"

    vCard.add('URL')
    vCard.url.value = 'https://www.facebook.com'
    vCard.url.type_param = "Facebook:"
```

In the output I was only able to get one of the link:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:justin.white@gmail.com
FN:Justin
N:White;Justin;;;
ORG:Tesla
TEL;TYPE=HOME:+16503977339
URL;TYPE=Facebook:https://www.facebook.com
URL:
END:VCARD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
v = vobject.vCard()
o = v.add('url')
o.type_param = "WEBSITE"
o.value = "website_link"

o = v.add('url')
o.type_param = "TWITTER"
o.value = "twitter_link"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.